# How to constrain a large image over multiple artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I am trying to place a large image over multiple artboards in illustrator. The image stretches over 8 artboards. I would like each artboard to be able to separate constraining the image proportions to each artboard. When I save as .ai and check separated artboards it will save the artboards individually but each board contains the entire image instead of the portion of the image I want.

Comment: Artboard never "split" images and there's no default method to make them operate that way. You'll have to *manually* create the tiles, or try saving artboards as PDFs. That may give you PDF pages of the "pieces"

Comment: Hi Stephanie, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

The Artboard never split an image unless you export it to Jpg using Artboard 
here is my solution:

1. arrange your artboard the way you want
2. place the image and stretch it over all your Artboard the way you want

[image]

3. export the file as JPG or TIF and check the checkbox `use Artboard`

[image]

4. Illustrator will export all your artboard into some individual images, you will notice that each Artboard will export a portion from the bidder image version. you will notice that each file name have a suffix with the artboard name. you will never get lost.

[image]

-- if you for artboard that have a portion of the bigger image individual so you have to continue with the next steps.

5. Now return to the illustrator and delete the bigger image.
6. place the images that you have just exported into illustrator each image in its artboard.

[image]

-- That's it.